# How to COPY a directory location?

Tags: command-line, paths

I've been struggling with this since I've installed Ubuntu:
How do I copy a directory location?

For example:

```
/home/user/downloads/game/game.sh
```

Do I have to type every single letter on terminal?
The problem is that there are some paths which are too long to see the entire directory.
So this isn't possible...

Anyway, again, I'm sorry, but someone, please help me out with this.

Comment: Copy a directory location to **_where_**?

Comment: Do you mean copy the path into the clipboard? In the terminal you need Ctrl+Shift+C to copy with shortcut key. Or if you mean you want to copy the directory to a new location, can you give an example? BTW, the `Downloads` directory usually has a capital letter - `downloads` is a different directory. I also wonder where the path is too long to be seen in full. Are you looking in the file browser? Which file manager/desktop environment? Which view?

Comment: The question is different. Copy the file or directory and paste on terminal. It will past the path and not the file or directory .

Answer (score 0):

If you cant use mouse, start typing directory name and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. In this case bash suggest you autocomplete for directories and files inside your location in File System: https://iridakos.com/tutorials/2018/03/01/bash-programmable-completion-tutorial.html

If you talk about terminal emulator, and can use mouse.. Just copy path to buffer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>) and paste it in terminal command to cursor location using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>